# Could not connect to JRUN server error customization

Tags: apache, error-handling, coldfusion-8

Is there a way to change the error message for coldfusion "Could not connect to JRUN server" to something more user friendly in apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the httpd.conf file edit the following line:

```
JRunConfig Errorurl url <optionally redirect to this URL on errors>
```

And put the URL of the page there, make sure it's not a coldfusion page.